# Is Nacos registry suitable for the registration of Dubbo 2.x？

Tags: microservices, spring-cloud, rpc, apache-dubbo

There is a feature of Nacos which make me feel confused while studying Nacos these days. it is single Nacos node in Nacos cluster will always hold full data.
It can be easy when our project use Spring Cloud and Feign for communication between our micro services, because each service should only hold the ip and port of the target service. Under the circumstances, the each service should only send its base information to the Nacos registry.
Well, when we use Dubbo2.x RPC framework for communication it will be obviously different. The Dubbo2.x will register all interfaces' meta information of single service, So single Nacos node will accept a sea of interfaces meta information. If we have hundreds of services and each service may expose a dozen RPC interfaces, the single Nacos node still hold full data.
Is Nacos registry suitable for the registration of Dubbo 2.x？ Can Nacos bear the stress of data storage? Can Nacos still performs well in this situation?

I know many RPC frameworks are able of registering to the Nacos. Why do they choose Nacos?